# Taylor Polynomial- Choosing A Point

Tags: calculus

How does the point we choose to develop the Taylor Polynomial has effect on the approximation?
I came across [Runge's phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon), so roughly speaking we can say we should not develop near the ends of the interval or where the function is not  differentiable?

Comment: Runge's phenomenon applies to a certain type of polynomial interpolation, not to Taylor polynomials, which are defined completely by the derivatives of a function at a single point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you linked does not really apply to taylor series. Taylor series have to converge in a disc on the complex plane. For example if you need $\log 3$ and you expand $\log x$ around $1$, it will only be valid in $[0,2]$ since log blows up at 0.

Or consider $\sqrt x$ This is the $50^{th}$ order taylor expansion about $0.1$:

[image]

Or consider $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. It blows up only for imaginary x, but that is enough to invalidate the taylor expansion:

[image]